# java Interpret simple expression

Tags: java, gson

I want to extend Gson library to enable field level custom translation, when we translate java bean to json string using gson.

something like this:

```
@Convert(expression="if(#value == '1') then 'enabled' else 'disabled'")
    private String roleStatus;
```

How to implement such a expression interpreter in java? Can spring expression do this ?

Comment: It feels like writing an expression parser for compile-time constants is overkill for this problem. After all, you have a powerful compiler already built to handle code that is constant at compile time: Java itself. You may want to use a custom serializer that can delegate to a default serializer, [as described here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-gson/FuGn-Hnt96I).

Comment: MVEL is exactly what I am looking for!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example your json is as below :

```
{
   "roleStatus" : "3"
   "role" : "guest"
}
```

**1. First you need to create Converter annotation field level as**

```
import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Inherited;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Documented
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Inherited
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Convertor {

    String expression();
}
```

**2. Then parse the gson custom level Deserialization with JsonDeserializer**

```
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import org.mvel2.MVEL;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContext;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParseException;

public class RoleStatusDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<RoleStatus> {

    @Override
    public RoleStatus deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT,
            JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {

        final JsonObject jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject();

        // get roleStatus from jsonObject and populate new roleStatus object
        final RoleStatus roleStatus = new RoleStatus(jsonObject.get("roleStatus").getAsString());

        final String expression = getFiledAnnotationValue();
        // Evaluate expression via Mvel.
        final String result = (String) MVEL.eval(expression, roleStatus);
         // update statusRole
        roleStatus.setRoleStatus(result);

        return roleStatus;
    }

    /**
     * reading Filed level annotation via java reflection
     * @return annoation value
     */
    private String getFiledAnnotationValue() {

        String expression = null;
        for (Field field : RoleStatus.class.getDeclaredFields()) {

            final Annotation annotation = field.getAnnotation(Convertor.class);

            if (annotation instanceof Convertor) {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                Convertor convertorAnnotation = (Convertor) annotation;
                expression = convertorAnnotation.expression();
                field.setAccessible(false);
            }
        }

        return expression;
    }
}
```

**3. get the annotation value(expression) inside RoleStatusDeserializer#deserialize() using java reflection**

**4.Once you get annotation expression value then you have to evaluate the expression value using [MVEL](http://mvel.codehaus.org/)**

MVEL is a powerful expression language for Java-based applications, most open source application are using mvel for el such as spring , warp-persist and others.
You can download Mvel latest version from [Mvel site](http://mvel.codehaus.org/)

**5. Finally parse it as**

```
JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new FileReader("your_path"));
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(RoleStatus.class,new RoleStatusDeserializer());
Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
RoleStatus roleStatus = gson.fromJson(reader, RoleStatus.class);
```

Comment: Thanks! I will check MVEL. by the way, I will overwrite some Gson classes to support filed level annotation which control how that filed will be proccessed, so no custom TypeAdaper need.